# How could I use a slug in InDesign as a digital client sign off?

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat, indesign-scripting, acrobat-scripting

I'm hoping to find a solution for a digital client sign off on artwork by using the digital signature feature in Acrobat but I'm hoping to be able to have this automatically set up in InDesign so I don't have to manually set the fields in Acrobat each time.

I've created a separate interactive PDF file that contains the fields I need and I can import this into the InDesign file but I can't include the slug when exporting as an interactive PDF.

Does anyone have a workaround? I can't resize the page to include the 'slug area' as this seems like a recipe for disaster.

If there is a better suited automated way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. A slug refers to an area outside of the boundaries of the document page, and by this definition how could you expect to output something that isn't visible.

Using Acrobat is quicker than InDesign and you can also create an action using the Action Wizard to create your sign off and then run that on a folder of documents to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this I've created a standard 1 page Indesign doc with interactive signature boxes text fields for signatures and print names. Then I copy and paste this page onto an extra page on each piece of  artwork.

I then export as an interactive PDF and send for approval.

As stated above there doesn't seem to be a way of including any area outside of the page area when exporting interactive PDFs and adding the fields in the PDF seemed a bit laborious when there are interactive options within Indesign.